# How to give gradient color to icon?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to give gradient color to icon. While this works on text tags,its not working on the icon for me. Any advice would be highly appreciated.

```css
.way_icon h3{
 font-size: 40px;      
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #e72c83 0%, #a742c6 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e72c83 0%,#a742c6 100%); 
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e72c83 0%,#a742c6 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;
```

```html
<div class="way_icon">
  <h3>jfkfjfjr<i class="ion-ios-gear"></i></h3>
  <a href="#"><i class="ion-ios-gear"></i></a>
</div>
<link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: also add the CSS of the icon so we can see it

Comment: initially i used .way_icon i ..to work only for the icon. now even though I insert i tag inside h1 ,it still doesntt take the css @TemaniAfif

Comment: In the code you share is there any icon ? :) no ... so to start you should first add icon to the code, then we can see the issue ;)

Comment: well ,<i class="ion-ios-gear"></i> is an ionicon

Comment: can you add ionicon cdn to the code so that the icon can be seen?

Comment: `well ,<i class="ion-ios-gear"></i> is an ionicon` and we need to see it :) it can be font, svg, image, etc etc ... if we aren't able to see it in the code, if you aren't able to show us the icon on where you want to apply your style we cannot help you

Comment: I have inserted the cdn..

Comment: the cdn not working

Comment: @TemaniAfif. I have modified the code now with a working cdn. The snippet will work now

Comment: your code work just fine in FF58.0.2

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1: WITH ION ICON**

```css
.way_icon h3 {
  font-size: 40px;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e72c83 0%, #a742c6 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e72c83 0%, #a742c6 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e72c83 0%, #a742c6 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.way_icon i:before {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="way_icon">
  <h3>Welcome <i class="ion-ios-gear"></i></h3>
  <a href="#"><i class="ion-ios-gear"></i></a>
</div>
```

**SOLUTION 2: With Font Awesome Icons**
I have tried to show here the solution with fontawesome icons.

```css
.way_icon h3 {
  font-size: 40px;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e72c83 0%, #a742c6 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e72c83 0%, #a742c6 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e72c83 0%, #a742c6 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.way_icon h3 .fa {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="way_icon">
  <h3>jfkfjfjr<i class="fa fa-cog"></i></h3>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: but he's not using Font awesome .. so how this solve his issue ? it need to work with ion icons

Comment: the ion icon cdn is being served from http. Which I could not add here. So for demo I added font awesome icons instead.

Comment: Added a solution with both font awesome and ion icon.

Comment: That second solution made my day. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here because `display:inline-block` is applied to the icons pseudo class `:before`..thats why your gradient is not working...

You have to set the `display: initial` to the icons pseudo elements

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.way_icon h3 {
  font-size: 40px;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e72c83 0%, #a742c6 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e72c83 0%, #a742c6 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #e72c83 0%, #a742c6 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.way_icon i:before {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="way_icon">
  <h3>Welcome <i class="ion-ios-gear"></i></h3>
  <a href="#"><i class="ion-ios-gear"></i></a>
</div>
```